# Is it possible to remove some specific instances to a Namespace Metric stre

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

I would like to create a metric stream from a namespace, but I dont need to half of the instances there. Is there any way to stream just some of the instances, or even just some of the metrics?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not from that menu. You would have to filter them using lambda function associated with your firehose delivery stream.

Comment: I wonder if having a lambda function to filter is cheaper than to just stream the data then ignore it on the other end?